How to flip mouse cursor behaviour on one axis?
I'm in posession of a touchpanel supposedly manufactured by IRTOUCH SYSTEMS unfortunately without the knowledge of its model number. Now my problem is that the (0,0) point of the touchpanel input is located in the top left corner, while the screen (0,0) point is in the bottom left corner. The result is that the input is flipped on the Y axis.
I want to flip the input back on this particular touchscreen and have taken some steps that didn't work:

calibration software of the IRTOUCH SYSTEMS - settings don't save there
Calibrate the screen for pen or touch input - Windows tool for calibration that is the closest to what I need: choose the monitor on which there will be the touchpanel, calibrate so that every pixel is covered with input area. One issue with this solution is that it doesn't work near the edges of the screen.
devcon.exe - override incerrect mappings to a device, device manager shows a couple of touchscreens and I'm unable to identify the correct one.
reaching out to the IRTOUCH SYSTEMS but with no answer from them

The platform is Windows 10. 
Is there any other fix that may work in this situation?
